# How to convert Milliseconds into date and use them in graph in JS

Tags: javascript, csv, date, graph

I trying to create a graph on the website. I am having problem to parse the timestamp from CSV file to JS. I am using papa parse to parse the CSV files.
I wanted to know how can I convert miliseconds into date/time and display them on the graph.

I have tried many things but I think Date.parse is correct way to do it and I have seen many examples online this is how far I have got.

This is how my CSV look like.

```
    Time    Power Production    Lighting
    Wed Apr 10 12:23:26 2019    3405.98 38.33
    Wed Apr 10 12:23:27 2019    3408.72 107.4
    Wed Apr 10 12:23:28 2019    3335.75 5.22
    Wed Apr 10 12:23:29 2019    3403.39 6.72
    Wed Apr 10 12:23:30 2019    3387.7  55.97
    Wed Apr 10 12:23:31 2019    3350.59 95.78
    Wed Apr 10 12:23:32 2019    3347.09 105.96
    Wed Apr 10 12:23:33 2019    3476.16 16.85
    Wed Apr 10 12:23:34 2019    3413.97 85.11
    Wed Apr 10 12:23:35 2019    3491.64 107.02
    Wed Apr 10 12:23:36 2019    3381.6  76.6
    Wed Apr 10 12:23:37 2019    3377.78 110.22
    Wed Apr 10 12:23:38 2019    3354.73 82.62
    Wed Apr 10 12:23:39 2019    3351.04 98.1
    Wed Apr 10 12:23:40 2019    3467.22 1.48
    Wed Apr 10 12:23:41 2019    3375.16 63.56
    Wed Apr 10 12:23:42 2019    3321.97 42.16
    Wed Apr 10 12:23:43 2019    3446.69 118.14
    Wed Apr 10 12:23:44 2019    3367.81 39.58
```

Here is my code

```
function createGraph3(data) {
var time = ['Time '];
var first = ['First Sensor'];
var second = ['Second Sensor'];

for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    time.push(Date.parse(data[i][0]));
    first.push(parseFloat(data[i][1]));
    second.push(parseFloat(data[i][2]));
}
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(time);


console.log(time);
console.log(first);


var powerr = c3.generate({
    bindto: '#powerr',
    data: {
        columns: [

            first,
            second
        ]
    },
    axis: {
        x: {
            type: 'category',
            categories: d, 
            tick: {
                multiline: false,
                culling: {
                    max: 4 
                }
        }
    }
    }
});

}  

parseData3(createGraph3);
```

How can I display the time stamp on the graph? I have been trying to figure it out but I am stuck.

Comment: "*I think Date.parse is correct way to do it*". Unfortunately, Date.parse is rarely the right way to parse anything. I don't see milliseconds in your data, I do see timestamps like "Wed Apr 10 12:23:26 2019" that appear to be DDD MMM DD HH:mm:ss YYYY (using moment.js tokens). Converting milliseconds is just `new Date(ms)`, provided *ms* is a number and not a string.

Comment: When I do Date.parse, I get values in ms

Comment: But you are parsing a non–standard string, so the result may be anything, including an invalid date. Manually parsing the string provides certainty and is but one more line of code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is your issue since you haven't provided a working example or what you expect as the result of the code, but:

```
var time = ['Time '];
```

Assigns an array to *time* with a single element, the string "Time". Then:

```
time.push(Date.parse(data[i][0]));
```

Adds an extra element, I guess a string like "Wed Apr 10 12:23:26 2019". The *for* loop adds one for each record (I suppose) so *time* looks like:

```
['Time ','Wed Apr 10 12:23:26 2019','Wed Apr 10 12:23:27 2019', ...];
```

Then there is:

```
var d = new Date();
d.setTime(time);
```

Which creates a new date, then attempts to set its time value to the value of *time* so is equivalent to:

```
d.setTime(['Time ','Wed Apr 10 12:23:26 2019','Wed Apr 10 12:23:27 2019', ...]);
```

When *setTime* is called, it first calls *ToNumber* on the value, which in the above case will almost certainly result in NaN, so the code is effectively:

```
d.setTime(NaN);
```

which results in an invalid date.